# Phonegap Build Push Notification plugin issue

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have a very strange issue that has been driving me nuts for a day now. I have a Phonegap Build 3.0 app and am trying to integrate the [Push plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/158). The problem is that even though I follow the documentation and many, many examples, the dang thing just wont work. I can not get it to fire the success or error callback and the try/catch reports no issues.

Head:

```
<head>
    <script src="assets/js/myScripts.js"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
</head>
```

myScripts.js

```
var myPushNotification;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    myPushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    try{
        myPushNotification.register(gcmRegistrationSuccessHandler, gcmRegistrationErrorHandler, {"senderID":"I have my Sender ID here","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});
    }
    catch(e){
        alert(e.message);//******this is never fired******
    }
}

function gcmRegistrationSuccessHandler(result){
    alert("successfully registered);//******this is never fired******
}

function gcmRegistrationErrorHandler(error){
    alert("error registering");//******this is never fired******
}
```

config.xml contains:

```
<access origin="*"/>

<gap:platform name="android" />
<gap:platform name="ios" />

<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update: I ran this in Phonegap Build's debug mode and attempted to directly call `myPushNotification.register(gcmRegistrationSuccessHandler, gcmRegistrationErrorHandler, {"senderID":"I have my Sender ID here","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});` and the log shows it returning as undefined where as calling `myPushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;` returns an opject like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. It turns out that the "gcmRegistrationSuccessHandler" callback in `myPushNotification.register(gcmRegistrationSuccessHandler, gcmRegistrationErrorHandler, {"senderID":"I have my Sender ID here","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});` is never called. Only the "onNotificationGCM" is called and you have to take all actions based on that. Sure wish that was documented...

Comment: I am stuck with the exact problem you have had Dom and still can't fix it, I tried anonymous functions as well as callback functions within my app still no luck, I still can't understand how you got it to work? this is my thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350971/phonegap-build-push-notification-android