# PhoneGap Build Push Notification (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I am having trouble receiving any type of callback for the [push notifications plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) for phonegap build, I have included the plugin inside config.xml.

I have signed up to [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and got my project number needed for pushNotification.register().

I also have access to the window.plugins.pushNotification object so I know it's included the plugin.

- **PhoneGap Build Version:** 3.1
- **Hydration:** Disabled
- **Debug:** Enabled
- **Device:** Samsung Tab 2

My **index.html** js files included are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/handlebars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars/helpers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/fastclick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

My **config.xml** plugins included are:

```
// plugins
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />
// access to external domains
<access origin="*"/>
```

My app.js call to pushNotification.register()

```
var app = {
init: function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function(){
       // DO STUFF
       // ....

       // ENABLE PUSH
       this.push_init();
    },

    push_init: function(){
        app.SENDER_ID = 123456789; // replaced by my actual GCM project no

        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

        pushNotification.register( 
            function(){alert('Push: win');}, // never called
            function(){alert('Push: Error');},  // never called
            { senderID: app.SENDER_ID, ecb: "app.push_android" }
        );
    },
   // never called
   push_android: function(e){
       alert('connection established...');
   console.log( 'successfully started android' );
   console.log( e );
   }

};

// start the app
app.init();
```

After that is called nothing is executed, app.push_android() is a function of app object.

If i don't enter a senderID I get an error saying no sender ID so I know that something is working. This is so frustrating any ideas?

**PS - I also noticed something weird, when I console.log the window.plugins.pushNotification it returns an empty object, however I can still call window.plugins.pushNotification.register(), but I thought I would be visible inside the console.log.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found the solution.

I was passing an integer instead of a string for the property senderID in the object

**Doesnt work**

```
pushNotification.register( 
    function(){alert('Push: win');}, // NOT called
    function(){alert('Push: Error');},  // NOT called
    { senderID: 123456789, ecb: "app.push_android" }
);
```

**DOES work**

```
pushNotification.register( 
    function(){alert('Push: win');}, // called
    function(){alert('Push: Error');},  // called
    { senderID: "123456789", ecb: "app.push_android" }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this push notification code -

```
var pushNotification;

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

function onDeviceReady() {

   try {
       pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
       if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
           pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, { "senderID": "123456789", "ecb": "onNotificationGCM" });    // required!
          }
      else {
          pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, { "badge": "true", "sound": "true", "alert": "true", "ecb": "onNotificationAPN" }); // required!
          }
      }  
    catch (err) {
        txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
        txt += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
        alert(txt);
     }
   };

// handle GCM notifications for Android
function onNotificationGCM(e) {
    switch (e.event) {
        case 'registered':
            if (e.regid.length > 0) {
                alert(e.regid);
                storeToken(e.regid);
            }
            break;

        case 'message':
            if (e.foreground) {
                var my_media = new Media("beep.wav");
                my_media.play();
            }
            else {  
              // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
            }

            break;

       case 'error':
           break;
       default:
          break;
    }
}
```

Refer [**Link**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

[**Refer Devgirl's Weblog**](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/)

Comment: Hi Suhas, thanks for help, but this didnt work, no error was thrown so it leads me to believe I am connecting to GCM but not callback function is getting called. They DEFINITELY exist within my app

Comment: PLease refer Devgirls blog. And this should work if you are added all java files in your project and properly put there path in "plugins.xml". And properly inserted pushnotification.js

Comment: Thanks again, I have checked that url originally. Like I mentioned in the original post, this is not for phonegap CLI, its phonegap build, no java files at all would be included in my www/ folder

Comment: @Suhas is there any solution for that too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620218/phonegap-push-plugin-not-working-on-android-4-0-4-and-below